# Интервалы в списке python

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, выборка

Дана выборка - например, [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 8, 11, 11] 
Также дано начало и длина интервала - например, 0 и 2.
Начинаем идти по интервалу от 0 включительно до 2 не включительно - получаем 0, 1, 1 - всего 3 числа. Количество чисел нужно добавить в новый список. Дальше от 2 включительно и до 4 не включительно - 2, 3 - всего 2 числа, добавляем в тот же список, дальше нужно сделать по аналогии. Как это реализовать? Перепробовал кучу вариантов, но ни один не отрабатывает. Python 3.6+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать двоичный поиск. Находим левую и правую границу и вычитаем из правой границы левую, чтобы узнать количество элементов в диапазоне.

```
import bisect

l = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 8, 11, 11]

leftIndex = bisect.bisect_left(l, 0)
rightIndex = bisect.bisect_left(l, 2)

print("Количество элементов в диапазоне [0;2):", rightIndex - leftIndex)
```

Answer (score 3):

Используя модуль [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html), это делается очень легко.

Для этого можно сначала [разложить все элементы по интервалам (корзинам)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), сгруппировать по интервалу и посчитать сколько элементов в каждом интервале:

```
In [22]: import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

In [23]: items =  [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 8, 11, 11]

In [24]: s = pd.Series(items)

In [25]: bins = list(range(0, max(items)+3, 2))

In [27]: res = s.groupby(pd.cut(s, bins=bins, right=False)).size()

In [28]: res
Out[28]:
[0, 2)      3
[2, 4)      2
[4, 6)      0
[6, 8)      1
[8, 10)     2
[10, 12)    2
dtype: int64

In [29]: res.to_list()
Out[29]: [3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2]
```

PS при работе с большими массивами данных Pandas работает на порядки быстрее обычного Python с использованием циклов